# phpmailer loop duplicated email addresses (and possible message) in loop

Tags: php, loops, phpmailer

I have the following code sending email shipping confirmations to my customers:

```
while ($i < count($tracked) ) {
try {
        //Server settings
        //$mail->SMTPDebug = SMTP::DEBUG_SERVER;                      // Enable verbose debug output
        $mail->isSMTP();                                            // Send using SMTP
        $mail->Host       = 'smtp.office365.com';                    // Set the SMTP server to send through
        $mail->SMTPAuth   = true;                                   // Enable SMTP authentication
        $mail->Username   = 'support@mycompany.com';                     // SMTP username
        $mail->Password   = 'password';                               // SMTP password
        $mail->SMTPSecure = PHPMailer::ENCRYPTION_STARTTLS;         // Enable TLS encryption; `PHPMailer::ENCRYPTION_SMTPS` also accepted
        $mail->Port       = 587;                                    // TCP port to connect to

        //Recipients
        $mail->setFrom('support@mycompany.com', 'mycompany');
        $mail->addAddress($tracked[$i]['customers_email_address'], $tracked[$i]['customers_name']);     // Add a recipient
        $mail->addReplyTo('support@mycompany.com', 'mycompany');


        // Content
        $mail->isHTML(true);                                  // Set email format to HTML
        $mail->Subject = EMAIL_TEXT_SUBJECT;
        $mail->Body    = $html;
$mail->AltBody = 'Your order with mycompany.com has shipped';
        $mail->send();
        echo 'order confirmation sent to order#:'.$tracked[$i]['orders_id'].'<br/>';
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        echo "Message could not be sent. Mailer Error: {$mail->ErrorInfo}";
    }
    $i++;
}
```

It appears to be sending to multiple emails. What I believe is happening is that in the while loop each new customers address is added to the list without clearing it. What doesnt seem to be happening though is the message does not seem to be duplicated? Wouldn't that duplicate at as well with each pass in the loop?

In any case I think the best thing to do before the try is:

```
$mail = new PHPMailer(true);
```

so that with each pass of the while loop the $mail object would be instantiated again. Is that proper? I know that the clearAllRecipients() function exists but i also want to be sure the body is cleaned as well.

Comment: Follow the advice in the [answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59618700/5260982) to take care of your address issue but I would also suggest that you move everything but the actual sending of the mail (`$mail->send();` and the echo) outside of the while loop. There is no reason to do all of the other things inside of the loop. Do it once and reuse it.

Answer (score 0):

it looks like your looping through an array of $tracked. Why not use a foreach loop? Then you don't need to use a counter.

```
    foreach ($tracked as $track ) {
try {
        //Server settings
        //$mail->SMTPDebug = SMTP::DEBUG_SERVER;                      // Enable verbose debug output
        $mail->isSMTP();                                            // Send using SMTP
        $mail->Host       = 'smtp.office365.com';                    // Set the SMTP server to send through
        $mail->SMTPAuth   = true;                                   // Enable SMTP authentication
        $mail->Username   = 'support@mycompany.com';                     // SMTP username
        $mail->Password   = 'password';                               // SMTP password
        $mail->SMTPSecure = PHPMailer::ENCRYPTION_STARTTLS;         // Enable TLS encryption; `PHPMailer::ENCRYPTION_SMTPS` also accepted
        $mail->Port       = 587;                                    // TCP port to connect to

        //Recipients
        $mail->setFrom('support@mycompany.com', 'mycompany');
        $mail->addAddress($track['customers_email_address'], $track['customers_name']);     // Add a recipient
        $mail->addReplyTo('support@mycompany.com', 'mycompany');


        // Content
        $mail->isHTML(true);                                  // Set email format to HTML
        $mail->Subject = EMAIL_TEXT_SUBJECT;
        $mail->Body    = $html;
$mail->AltBody = 'Your order with mycompany.com has shipped';
        $mail->send();
        echo 'order confirmation sent to order#:'.$track['orders_id'].'<br/>';
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        echo "Message could not be sent. Mailer Error: {$mail->ErrorInfo}";
    }
}
```

Comment: That would clean things up slightly (just get rid of counter) but it would still have the same issue where the setFrom is continuously adding a new email address for each loop no?

Answer (score 0):

It's because `addAddress()` does exactly what its name suggests; it **adds** an address that a message will be sent to. It doesn't **set** the addresses a message will be sent to.

Unsurprisingly there is a method that allows you to clear the list of addresses, called `clearAddresses()`, so just call that at the end of your sending loop after `send()` and your issue will be solved.

I'd also recommend that you base your code on [the mailing list example provided with PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/examples/mailing_list.phps) as it will be much faster than the code you have here. Also read the docs on sending to listshttps://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Sending-to-lists) for furtehr advice.

Comment: Makes sense thanks. I have added clearAddresses to the end of each loop and will adjust it so that we are not setting the same items that don't change over and over. One question though, the body does change in every email (slightly the tracking numbers and order numbers change for example). does setting the body clear the previous body?

Comment: Yes; the body is just a regular property.